# Unable to set translate domain for gtk builder file, GTK+ 2

Tags: internationalization, gtk, gtkbuilder

I want to internationalize my gtk+2 app. I can do it if i've strings in source code(_("String")). I extracted all strings from .ui file using the **xgettext**. It's OK. I translated it. 
I want to set **text domain** for my interface file using:

```
gtk_builder_set_translation_domain(builder, GETTEXTPATH)
```

It doesn't works. All strings are same as at the beginning.
I'm using GTK+ 2.24.10. I don't want to get all strings in program and use **_()**.

Comment: Are you calling `gtk_builder_set_translation_domain()` **before** `gtk_builder_add_from_file()`?

Comment: If I call 'gtk_builder_set_translation_domain()' before 'gtk_builder_add_from_file()' It doesn't works, if i call it after 'gtk_builder_add_from_file()' is as previously :/

Comment: Saying "it does not work" is quite unhelpful: (1) `gtk_builder_set_translation_domain()` must be called before loading the file, this is not an option (otherwise the GUI will be not translated, that is you'll get what you get); (2) you can use the `error` argument of `gtk_builder_add_from_file()` to inspect the eventual error you get; (3) `GETTEXTPATH` stinks: it is expected a domain name, not a path.